# My angular app is not getting build with the following error

Tags: angular, build

```
        ERROR in src/app/home/home.component.ts(311,9): error TS2322: Type 
        'Response' is not assignable to type 'String'.
        src/app/home/home.component.ts(311,9): error TS2322: Type 
       'Response' is not assignable to type 'String'.
        Property 'padStart' is missing in type 'Response'.
        src/app/home/home.component.ts(336,5): error TS2554: Expected 2-3 
        arguments, but got 1. 
        src/app/home/home.component.ts(348,5): error TS2554: Expected 2-3 
        arguments, but got 1.
        src/app/home/home.component.ts(366,11): error TS2339: Property 
       'message' does not exist on type 'Response'.
        src/app/home/home.component.ts(367,43): error TS2339: Property 
       'data' does not exist on type 'Response'.
```

The relvant code block for the reason of below error is working fine and it compiles well in my browser. Can I ignore the warnings?? how to build by ignoring the errors?

```
//rnadom number generator
randomnumbergenerate() {
  let urlSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();
  urlSearchParams.append('mid', '91');
  urlSearchParams.append('tabname', 'account');
  urlSearchParams.append('fname', 'accountnumber');
  urlSearchParams.append('fnameid', '2875');
  this.http.post('http://localhost/example_org/Base/randomnumgenerate', urlSearchParams).subscribe(
    data => {
      this.randomNumber = data,
        console.log(data);
    },
    error => {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(error.json()));
    }
  )
}
```

this is another function which is creating error.

```
//get Notification data 
loadfeedend(){
  let urlSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();
  urlSearchParams.append('datatype', 'my');
  urlSearchParams.append('lastnode', '1');
  this.http.post('http://localhost/example_org/Base/getnotificationdata', urlSearchParams).subscribe(
    data => {
      this.notificationData = data,
        console.log(data);
    },
    error => {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(error.json()));
    }
  )
}
```

this is another function which is creating error.

```
//get Notification count 
getnotificationcount(){
  this.http.post('http://zlocalhost/example_org/Base/getnotificationcount').subscribe(
    data => {
      this.notificationCount = data,
        console.log(data);
    },
    error => {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(error.json()));
    }
  )

}
```

this is another function which is creating error.

```
//reset notification counter
resetnotificationcount(){
  this.http.post('http://localhost/example_org/Base/resetnotificationcounter').subscribe(
    data => {
      console.log('reset done');
    },
    error => {
    }
  )
}
```

this is another function which is creating error.

```
//notification icon click
notificationfetch() {
  this.loadfeedend();
  this.getnotificationcount();
  this.resetnotificationcount();
}
```

this is another function which is creating error.

```
//column name data load
loadcolumnname(moduleid) {
  this.http.get('http://localhost/example_org/Base/newsetmainviewcolumndata?moduleid=91').subscribe(
    data => {
      if(data.message == 'Success') { //for set data in view select process
        console.log('all data fetch done',data.data);
      } else {
        console.log('failure-->',data.desc);
      }
    },
    error => {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(error.json()));
    }
  )
```

this is another function which is creating error.

```
  this.http.get('http://localhost/example_org/Base/loadcolumnname?moduleid=91').subscribe(
    data => {
      if(data.message == 'Success') { //for set data in view select process
        console.log('column fetch done',data.data);
      } else {
        console.log('failure-->',data.desc);
      }
    },
    error => {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(error.json()));
    }
  )
}
```

This is one part of home.ts where most of the errors are getting generated.
  Now this errors can be removed asap.

On top of that another error that I am very eager to solve is this

```
ERROR in Error during template compile of
'MaterialDesignFrameworkModule'
Could not resolve @angular/flex-layout relative to
C:/Users/salesneuronpc1/Desktop/salesneuronver4_prod/node_modules/angular2-json-schema-form/angular2-json-schema-form.d.ts..
```

Comment: Don't ignore warnings, and definitely don't ignore errors. 
Post your home.component.ts code

Comment: brother this is compile-time error please post your  home.component.ts code

Comment: Ok sure, I am posting it here...just updating it.